# docker ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I trying access docker folder but I can't looks like it is about permission, but I don't want make this folder opened for security reasons.

I am using root user already, so how I will be able to access this folder? without open it?

it is another user for the docker folder? how to find out?

```
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:/var/lib/docker$ cd ..
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:/var/lib$ ls -lrt
drwx--x--x 14 root          root          4096 Nov 20 17:52 docker
```

Answer (score 3):

The read permissions on the directory are not set, meaning that you can't list its contents.  You can access them if you know the name.

Comment: how to set it ? @Ricardo Branco

Comment: @vignesh with `chmod a+r /var/lib/docker`